# magento change client pdf invoice

Tags: magento

I am working on a magento e-shop and trying to add client's vat number at the invoice that is generated from the frontend (at client's panel).
I searched and found that editting files:
`app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php`
`app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php`
is the appropriate way.
Editting those files results in changes only at the pdf invoice that is generated in the admin's panel.
How can i add the vat number at the pdf that is generated at the **client's** panel? (It is different from the pdf that is generated at the admin's panel)